# .NET Remoting slows down when internet connection starts up

Tags: c#, .net, performance, remoting, lag

I have been using .net remoting with client and server on my dev machine, and everything was fine. And then I've located the server on the other machine, connected with my through a 100-Mbit LAN. It has a VPN connection, allowing it to connect to the internet.

Whenever a VPN connection is started, .NET remoting gives out huge lag for every query(1s for 0.03s query and 9s for 1.3s query). But the speed between my machine and the server one with VPN enabled is still 100 Mbit/s.

I'm using binary tcp channel.

Does anyone know of solution to this problem ?

Comment: Do you need to go over the VPN to connect to your server from your dev machine, or is the VPN configured on the server machine?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using the bindTo configuration property for the server channel configuration.
It seems that when there are more than one 1 network interface, remoting doesn't know which one to use and analyzes all data. 
After setting bindTo ip address lag was gone.